# Why are my cloned linux VMs fighting for the same IP

Tags: systemd, virtual-machine, dhcp, systemd-networkd

I've cloned two vSphere VMs off of an Ubuntu 17.10 template. After boot, they both claim the same IP and fight for it (ssh connections break off as the IP switches between them).

The hostnames and MAC addresses are different between the two machines. `dhclient` correctly claims two separate IPs, but the resolver in use is `systemd-networkd`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What about netplan configuration? There is an option `dhcp-configuration` that can be used as follows (excerpt from [netplan examples](https://netplan.io/examples)):

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp-identifier: mac
```

by default it is using machine-id, but by changing this feature we can 'force' it not to.

Excerpt from [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/netplan.5.html)/[netplan](https://netplan.io/reference), giving more insights:

```
       dhcp-identifier (scalar)
              When  set  to `mac'; pass that setting over to systemd-networkd to use the device's
              MAC address as a unique identifier rather than a RFC4361-compliant Client ID.  This
              has no effect when NetworkManager is used as a renderer.
```

Comment: Great solution for a VM image.

Answer (score 36):

`systemd-networkd` uses a different method to generate the DUID than `dhclient`. `dhclient` [by default uses the link-layer address](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/isc-dhcp-client/dhclient.8.en.html) while `systemd-networkd` uses [the contents of `/etc/machine-id`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/networkd.conf.html#DUIDType=). Since the VMs were cloned, they have the same `machine-id` and the DHCP server returns the same IP for both.

To fix, you need to generate a new `/etc/machine-id`. According to [Is it OK to change /etc/machine-id?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402999/is-it-ok-to-change-etc-machine-id), the best way to do this is delete `/etc/machine-id` and reboot -- the boot process on most systems will generate a new `/etc/machine-id` automatically. Thanks to JdeBP and Andy Fraley for the additional information.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402999/ for why that does not work, what one actually has to do, and what state the machine has to be in to do it.

Comment: Interesting. Good catch. +1

Comment: Wow.  I've been banging my head on this one.  I'm finally getting different IPs after following your suggestion.  Although, onto my next issue.  I cannot seem to ping the VMs from Host.  Ugg!

Comment: Nevermind.  Problem solved.  Thx for your post!

Comment: `netplan ip leases ensX` will give you the `CLIENTID` including the DUID if you want to check it by hand.

Comment: On 20.04 you do not have to mess with /var/lib/dbus/machine-id, it's just a symlink to /etc/machine-id.  The only thing you need to do is clear the contents of /etc/machine-id and reboot.  Note that deleting the file breaks dhcp, instead clear the contents like `> /etc/machine-id` or `truncate -s0 /etc/machine-id`.  Lastly, if you're making templates be sure to run `cloud-init clean` as well.

Comment: @JdeBP I don't under stand your comment "*See unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402999 for why that does not work, what one actually has to do, and what state the machine has to be in to do it.*" .... Can you elaborate

Comment: @Abdull, from what I understand, you shouldn't continue using the system after this, but immediately reboot. Since most systems generate a `machine-id` on reboot if it doesn't exist, it's "safer" to delete the file and reboot the VM to generate a new one. I've edited my answer to factor in this information.